# Array returning NULL, but I can see the data var_dump(....). See Code

Tags: php, var-dump

I have a function:

```
function getTrend($results, $region, $monthNo)
{
    $dateMap = getLastNMonths(6);
    $keys = array_keys($dateMap);
    $val = $results[$region][$keys[$monthNo]];

    if(isset($val))
    {
        return round($val, 2);
    }
    else {
        return '0.00';
    }
}
```

..where $val is returning NULL. Now I know there is data in $dateMap and $keys from doing a var_dump() on them...

Here is a couple lines from $results:

> array(21) { ["01"]=> array(5) { ["01-SEP-11"]=> string(40)
>   "596.386666666666666666666666666666666667" ["01-OCT-11"]=> string(40)
>   "639.347666666666666666666666666666666667" ["01-NOV-11"]=> string(40)
>   "857.364833333333333333333333333333333333" ["01-DEC-11"]=> string(40)
>   "663.022833333333333333333333333333333333" ["01-JAN-12"]=> string(41)
>   "1094.066833333333333333333333333333333333" } ["02"]=> array(5) {
>   ["01-SEP-11"]=> string(8) "510.1675" ["01-OCT-11"]=> string(8)
>   "542.4725" ["01-NOV-11"]=> string(8) "809.4245" ["01-DEC-11"]=>
>   string(40) "314.023833333333333333333333333333333333" ["01-JAN-12"]=>
>   string(40) "913.979666666666666666666666666666666667" } ["03"]=>
>   array(5) { ["01-SEP-11"]=> string(40)
>   "594.528333333333333333333333333333333333" ["01-OCT-11"]=> string(40)
>   "465.415333333333333333333333333333333333" ["01-NOV-11"]=> string(40)
>   "508.904666666666666666666666666666666667" ["01-DEC-11"]=> string(8)
>   "355.6895" ["01-JAN-12"]=> string(7) "706.928" } ["04"]=> array(5) {
>   ["01-SEP-11"]=> string(40) "112.094833333333333333333333333333333333"
>   ["01-OCT-11"]=> string(40) "399.436666666666666666666666666666666667"
>   ["01-NOV-11"]=> string(40) "193.798166666666666666666666666666666667"
>   ["01-DEC-11"]=> string(40) "246.241666666666666666666666666666666667"
>   ["01-JAN-12"]=> string(40) "582.542333333333333333333333333333333333"
>   } ["WOCB"]=> array(5) { ["01-SEP-11"]=> string(40) "216.045166666666666666666666666666666667" ["01-OCT-11"]=> string(40) "139.774333333333333333333333333333333333" ["01-NOV-11"]=> string(7) "254.421" ["01-DEC-11"]=> string(7) "142.355" ["01-JAN-12"]=> string(40) "119.464666666666666666666666666666666667" } ["NONE"]=> array(5) { ["01-SEP-11"]=> string(7) "427.196" ["01-OCT-11"]=> string(40) "430.996333333333333333333333333333333333" ["01-NOV-11"]=> string(40) "259.113666666666666666666666666666666667" ["01-DEC-11"]=> string(40) "188.372166666666666666666666666666666667" ["01-JAN-12"]=> string(40) "332.743333333333333333333333333333333333" } }

Here is a couple lines from $dateMap:

> array(6) { ["01-SEP-2011"]=> string(14) "September 2011"
>   ["01-OCT-2011"]=> string(12) "October 2011" ["01-NOV-2011"]=>
>   string(13) "November 2011" ["01-DEC-2011"]=> string(13) "December
>   2011" ["01-JAN-2012"]=> string(12) "January 2012" ["01-FEB-2012"]=>
>   string(13) "February 2012" } array(6) { ["01-SEP-2011"]=> string(14)
>   "September 2011" ["01-OCT-2011"]=> string(12) "October 2011"
>   ["01-NOV-2011"]=> string(13) "November 2011" ["01-DEC-2011"]=>
>   string(13) "December 2011" ["01-JAN-2012"]=> string(12) "January 2012"
>   ["01-FEB-2012"]=> string(13) "February 2012" } array(6) {
>   ["01-SEP-2011"]=> string(14) "September 2011" ["01-OCT-2011"]=>
>   string(12) "October 2011" ["01-NOV-2011"]=> string(13) "November 2011"
>   ["01-DEC-2011"]=> string(13) "December 2011" ["01-JAN-2012"]=>
>   string(12) "January 2012" ["01-FEB-2012"]=> string(13) "February 2012"
>   }

Here is a couple lines from $keys:

> array(6) { [0]=> string(11) "01-SEP-2011" [1]=> string(11)
>   "01-OCT-2011" [2]=> string(11) "01-NOV-2011" [3]=> string(11)
>   "01-DEC-2011" [4]=> string(11) "01-JAN-2012" [5]=> string(11)
>   "01-FEB-2012" } array(6) { [0]=> string(11) "01-SEP-2011" [1]=>
>   string(11) "01-OCT-2011" [2]=> string(11) "01-NOV-2011" [3]=>
>   string(11) "01-DEC-2011" [4]=> string(11) "01-JAN-2012" [5]=>
>   string(11) "01-FEB-2012" } array(6) { [0]=> string(11) "01-SEP-2011"
>   [1]=> string(11) "01-OCT-2011" [2]=> string(11) "01-NOV-2011" [3]=>
>   string(11) "01-DEC-2011" [4]=> string(11) "01-JAN-2012" [5]=>
>   string(11) "01-FEB-2012" } array(6) { [0]=> string(11) "01-SEP-2011"
>   [1]=> string(11) "01-OCT-2011" [2]=> string(11) "01-NOV-2011" [3]=>
>   string(11) "01-DEC-2011" [4]=> string(11) "01-JAN-2012" [5]=>
>   string(11) "01-FEB-2012" } array(6) { [0]=> string(11) "01-SEP-2011"
>   [1]=> string(11) "01-OCT-2011" [2]=> string(11) "01-NOV-2011" [3]=>
>   string(11) "01-DEC-2011" [4]=> string(11) "01-JAN-2012" [5]=>
>   string(11) "01-FEB-2012" }

$monthNo can equal either 0,1,2,3,4,5. For example:

> $mo2 = getTrend($results, $region, 1);

My question is, why can I not see anything from $val? What am I missing here? Did I show you enough code? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this part:

```
array(21) { ["01"]=> array(5) { ["01-SEP-11"]=> string(40) ...
```

Look at the key - it's `"01"` in quotes.  That means it's a string, so you would have to do

```
$results["01"]
```

to get at that key.  If you're passing in

```
$results[1]
```

It's not going to show up.  When you initially populate `$results` that key should be cast it to an `int`

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the reply. That was quick! So, $results could have a string in there too... It could also have this: ["WOCB"]=> array(5) { ["01-SEP-11"]=> string(40) "216.045166666666666666666666666666666667" ["01-OCT-11"]=> string(40) "139.774333333333333333333333333333333333" ["01-NOV-11"]=> string(7) "254.421" ["01-DEC-11"]=> string(7) "142.355" ["01-JAN-12"]=> string(40) "119.464666666666666666666666666666666667" } ["NONE"]=> array(5) { ["01-SEP-11"]=> ....

Comment: IE... REGION Could be WOCB or 01

Comment: OK so you just need to call `getTrend` like this:  `$mo2 = getTrend($results, $region, "01");`

Answer (score 2):

**The problem is you have an associative array and you want to access it like an indexed array.**

> In PHP, there are three types of arrays:
>
> **Indexed arrays** - Arrays with a numeric index
>
> **Associative arrays** - Arrays with named keys
>
> **Multidimensional arrays** - Arrays containing one or more arrays
>
> [More about arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)

You cannot access a value of an associative array like

`echo $results[1];`

because you have strings in the keys of your array. `$results["01"]`

*Well, what happens when you do not know the key of your array and its being generated dynamically?*

If you do not know the key to the array, you will have to use `array_values`. This function takes an array and spits back out an array, but the return array is indexed 0,1,2... the keys are lost but the values are not.

To get the value of an array at index 1 of an associative array

`echo array_values($results)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

"result" return null, index 01 != 1

```
var_dump(isset($val)); // false
```